# Bash Loop - How to stop the loop when I press Control-C inside a command?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, command-line-interface, job-control

I am rsyncing a few directories. I have a bash terminal open and am executing something like this:

```
for DIR in * ; do rsync -a $DIR example.com:somewhere/ ; done
```

However if I want to stop the whole things, I press Control-C. That stops the rsync, but then it keeps going to the next one. In this case I realize what has happened and then just press Control-C like a madman until things work again.

Is there some way to 'fix' this. I want it so if I have a loop like that, and press Control-C, that it will return me to my bash shell.

Comment: Dennis' answer is the right one, but you if you didn't do that, you don't have to 'press it like a madman', just hold it and let the keyboard repeat handle it :-)

Comment: I always just hold down Cntl-C, generally works fine.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
for DIR in * ; do rsync -a $DIR example.com:somewhere/ || break; done
```

This will also exit the loop if an individual rsync run fails for some reason.

Comment: Additional tip: if you're in a nested loop, and want to completely terminate, use `break 2` (or replace "2" with the number of nested loops you want to terminate).

Answer (score 40):

To expand on Dennis' answer, your code might look like:

```
trap "echo Exited!; exit;" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

For a working example (that happens to involve rsync), check out http://gist.github.com/279849.

Comment: Thanks, this is a generic solution that worked for me

Comment: Best answer I think. Trapping both `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` seems to more-consistently kill an infinite while loop than trapping `SIGINT` alone. UPDATE: eh, maybe not. I'm not sure. I still get some occasions where I have to hit Ctrl + C twice! I'm not sure why.

Comment: The OP said they were running in a shell, not a shell script. Therefore this will not work.

Answer (score 30):

You can set a trap for Control-C.

```
trap <command> SIGINT
```

will execute the `command` when Control-C is pressed. Just put the `trap` statement somewhere in your script at a point where you want it to become effective.

Comment: Example: to force an exit with code `2` whenever Ctrl + C is pressed: `trap 'exit 2' SIGINT`

Comment: Even better: also print `Ctrl + C` just prior to exiting with return code `2`: `trap 'printf "%s\n" "Ctr + C"; exit 2' SIGINT`

Comment: I can also confirm that `SIGINT` alone doesn't always seem to work to kill an infinite while loop. Doing `trap <cmd> SIGINT SIGTERM`, [as this answer shows](https://serverfault.com/a/160961/357116), seems to work better.

Comment: The OP said they were running in a shell, not a shell script. Therefore this will not work for the OP question.

Comment: @Oliver: The OP is running a loop. That is "script-like".

Comment: @denniswilliamson There's a big difference between exiting a loop and exiting a script. What command will you run to break the loop in a shell  (not a shell script), without exiting the shell?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: OP question: "I have a bash terminal open"

Answer (score 18):

1. Press `Ctrl-Z` to suspend the script ;
2. `kill %%`

Credits, explanations and more details in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48465/26952).

Comment: This is great because it works "post facto" when you want to interrupt a long-running loop you already started.

Comment: the best answer, thank you!

Comment: This is the best solution because it works even if you forget to add the `|| break` (@kenster answer) or the parentheses (@amphetamachine answer)

Answer (score 10):

When you put a string of commands inside parentheses, the string will act as a single process, and will receive the SIGINT and terminate when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
(for DIR in * ; do rsync -a "$DIR" example.com:somewhere/ ; done)
```

But! In the case of the `rsync` command, it allows multiple sources, so the code you wrote would be better-written as:

```
rsync -a * example.com:somewhere/
```

Comment: This should be at the top. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to put another command in my loop that can easily be interrupted.  It requires two ctrl-C's to be pressed.

```
for DIR in * ; do rsync -a $DIR example.com:somewhere/ ; sleep 1 ; done
```

It's not such a great solution for this rsync, which you probably want to run quickly.  But it does work well for other loops, like this one:

```
while true ; do ping -c 10 example.com ; sleep 1 ; done
```

This loop will re-lookup the address of example.com every time through the loop, which is useful if you're watching for a DNS change.